# Showing that a function has at least three roots

Tags: roots, factoring

I am working on the following problem:

Show that the function $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}, f(x) = 2^{x} - 4x^{2} + x + 3$ has at least three roots.

So I have to show where $f(x) = 0$ but I cannot factor the polynomial because of the exponential. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Try looking for sign changes.  Note that you are not required to produce the actual roots.

Comment: But the sign changes only twice?

Comment: Check the signs at $x=-1,0,2,8$. Or at $x=-\infty,0,2,+\infty$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you came to these values?

Comment: Just go for cheap values $f(\pm \infty)=\pm \infty$.  $f(0)>0$.   The only subtle one is that $f(3)<0$ (or $f(2), f(4), f(5)\cdots$.

Comment: $f(x) = 0$ means $2^x = 4x^2 - x + 3$. It is not too hard to plot approximate graphs of both of these curves, which will tell you roughly where two roots are. Since there are three, you would have to get more accurate in your graphing. But at one of the first two roots, the graphs cross cleanly in different directions, while near the other the graphs are similar. This tells you to investigate near that root for the other crossing. More particularly, this tells you where to look for the values with $f(x) < 0, f(x) > 0$ that prove roots must be between them.